# pgfplots bar plot number format

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

I was just trying to compile some data into a bar chart using pgfplots. Things seem to work apart from the following: The annotation for the bars has low precision, i.e. only 3 decimals, it is shown as "1.02 \cdot 10^6". Is there a way to change it to the actual value (1022641)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=500000,
    width=12cm,enlarge y limits=0.5,
    xlabel={Travel time [s]},
    symbolic y coords={hello},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {(1022641,hello)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Add `every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,1000 sep={}}` to your options.

Comment: I added it like so: `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node ...]` but no change

Comment: @hfhc2: Add it to `\begin{axis}[...]`, or add it as `\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every node ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I ended up doing the following: I first defined a style outside of the actual `\tikzpicture`:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    default style/.style={
    xbar, xmin=0,
    width=12cm,enlarge y limits=0.5,
    xlabel={Travel time [s]},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,1000 sep={}}
    }
}
```

which contains the modification which percusse and Jake suggested. The actual plot uses the defined style:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    default style,
    symbolic y coords={hello}
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {(1022641,hello)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This way the style and the data are decoupled and the style is reusable.